# How to return parametrised model to a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I cannot return a completed Model from my View to my Controller

If I use the following code I get the value of IsSelected returned to my Action for every item in the Model.
However, I get a Null for the Thing object.

The Thing object is a large data object containing other data objects

Any ideas on where I have gone wrong?

I have the following code;

## View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("myAction", "myController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Thing .CaseID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Thing .Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().IsSelected)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Thing.Index",i)
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Thing.CaseNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Thing.CaseTitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].IsSelected)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>

<input type="submit" name="SaveButton" value="Save" />
}
```

## Controller

```
public ActionResult myAction(ICollection<SelectThingViewModel> caseViewModels)
{
    return View("ShowFoundThings");
}
```

## ViewModel

```
public class SelectThingViewModel
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    private Thing thing;

    public SelectThingViewModel(Thing thing, bool isSelected)
    {
        this.IsSelected = isSelected;
        this.thing= thing;
    }

    public SelectThingViewModel()
    {
    }

    public Thing thing
    {
        get { return _thing; }
        set { _case = value; }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Select")]
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { _isSelected = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `case` (lower cased) is a reserved keyword in C#, you may need to prefix it with an `@` symbol, like `public Case @case`, but ideally you should just capitalize it. I'm not sure if this is your problem but technically `case` is not allowed to be used as an identifier anywhere in a C# program (reserved for `switch` statements).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not actually using "case" in the code.  I cleaned up the code example to remove the real names to protect the innocent.  I'll use something else so as not to muddy the waters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayFor does not return values when you submit.  you need to have the values inside an `<input>`.. in your case you should use `@Html.HiddenFor`

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Case.CaseNumber)
    @Hmlt.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Case.CaseNumber)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Case.CaseTitle)
    @Hmlt.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Case.CaseTitle)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].IsSelected)
</td>
```

`@Html.DisplayFor()` by default will just add plain text to your view, so your output for `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Case.CaseNumber)</td>` would look like `<td>12345</td>` without the value being inside some type of input field the value will not get posted to your action.  Using the above code would give you something like this

```
<td>
    12345
    <input name="[1].Case.CaseNumber" type="hidden" value="12345" />
</td>
```

with the value of the input being posted, but not visible on in the view.